# template and function call

Tags: function, templates

Hey I'm relatively new to c++ and was wondering if anyone would tell me why this won't compile. I get errors like "no matching function for call to 'search(int[10],int)'" and "template argument deduction/substitution failed" The program is supposed to search the int array for the number 5, the char array for 'm' and the string array for "nuts"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


template<class T>
void search(T& a, T& b)
{
T temp = a;
T temp2= b;
int index=0;
bool found = false;
while((!found))
{
    if(temp2==temp[index])
    {
        found = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        index++;
    }
}
if(found)
{
    cout << temp[index] 
    << "is located at index: " << index << endl;
}
}


int main()
{
int intarray[10]={3,5,9,14,15,19,21,34,47,52};
char chararray[10]={'b','d','e','g','i','k','m','o','r','t'};
string stringarray[10]={"all","big","cats","eat","food","grapes","hats","kelp","nuts", "rats"};

search(intarray, 5);
search(chararray, 'm');
search(stringarray, "nuts");
}
```